# Convert a column to an array in GCP BQ

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to GCP BQ. I have a query that return data in following format as in input in the image. I want it converted to the output. I tried unnest , array_agg but was not able to get a solution. I would appreciate any help.

first query is really simple:

```
select col1, col2 from table where partitionid=>0 and partitionid<=1000 group by col1,col2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired result, you can use the `STRING_AGG` function in BigQuery to concatenate the values of col2 for each distinct value of col1.

Here's an updated version of your query that includes the STRING_AGG function:

[image: results]

Comment: That sounds promising. But my values are BOOL and no matching signature for aggregate function error occurred .This I fixed by  using CAST.
But not all values are returned , nulls are skipped by this query when I use cast.

Comment: You can simply do `CAST(IFNULL(col2, 'NULL') AS STRING)`.